# Mysql master slave get error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I did not get this bug when I only run one server. But if I try to enable master slave for mysql (1 master and two slaves) and I insert record to a InnoDB table, I get the following error

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction".

Below is my configuration for master db:

```
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
server-id=99
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
replicate-ignore-db=mysql
replicate-ignore-db=information_schema
replicate-ignore-db=performance_schema
```

Please help, thanks so much